# How to use Unicode characters in yout HTML applications - inline and data binding?

Tags: html, data-binding, unicode

What escape characters can be used to insert unicode characters in HTML apps.

Comment: If you use UTF-8, you don't need to escape anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inserting Unicode characters in HTML, wrap your HEX value start with `&#x` and end with `;`

When data-binding like knockout start the HEX value with `\u`

Answer (score 0):

If your document is a UTF-8 document and you are sending the corresponding `content-type` header and/or meta element, you can simply use the characters without escaping.

All modern browsers understand this Unicode encoding and will display them correctly (assuming the OS on the client has the right fonts installed).